# insert image in text widget without using imageTK

Tags: python, tkinter

Unfortunately I'm developing under a osx machine where I've been unable to install imageTK...

I need to insert an image taken from a dictionary of images, saved thus:

```
i = open(filename, 'rb')
i.seek(0)
w = i.read()
i.close()
allicons[d]=w
```

so at insert time I don't have a filename, just the dict.

with imageTk, this works:

```
c = cStringIO.StringIO()
c.write(allicons[key])
c.seek(0)
im = Image.open(c)
iconimage=ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
config.text.image_create(INSERT, image=iconimage)
```

but I don't know how to do it without imageTk.
Just with "import Image", I tried:

```
im = Image.open(c)
iconimage = PhotoImage(im)
```

and iconimage is recognized (TkInter.PhotoImage object ...),
but inserting it I get a "TypeError: **str** returned non-string (type instance) ... in image_create  *self._options(cnf, kw))"

... any help really appreciated, thanks!

alessandro

Comment: Without PIL I don't like your chances. (unless your images are all in gif format). Search this site OR http://www.mail-archive.com/image-sig@python.org/ for ways of getting PIL to work on osx.

Comment: YES! Just for this reason I took care to convert any image that went into allicons[] to GIF. So... ho would you do it with gifs???

Comment: Tkinter's built-in PhotoImage class can read gif straight from the file, eg. pic = PhotoImage(file='whatever.gif'). Then all you need to do is insert it: text.image_create(END, image=pic).

Comment: thanks, but in my case I cannot use it, since the image isnt in a file but in the dictionary, as the code shows. How can I use the PhotoImage class without a file?

Comment: Any reason the images can't be in a file (as gif)? Anyway, PhotoImage also has a 'data' option. You can supply it with gif data that's been encoded using base64. something like: dat = base64.encodestring(allicons[key]), then pic = PhotoImage(data=dat)

Comment: at last! Thanks a lot, it worked... How can I accept this answer? Please, re-input it as an answer not as a comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhotoImage has a 'data' option. You can supply it with gif data that's been encoded using base64. something like:

```
dat = base64.encodestring(allicons[key])
pic = PhotoImage(data=dat)
...
```